# Why are the leaves on my young avocado tree drooping?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, indoors, avocado

This young avocado tree was grown from an avocado seed and is about 6 months old.  I live in Tucson, Arizona and keep it inside my house by a south facing window.  There's no direct sunlight in this spot.

Why are the leaves drooping like this?

[![Right side up][1]][1]

Updated pictures

Updated pictures of leaves 9/17

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c4PT.jpg[image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Welcome RobinK! Thanks for your detailed question! Your picture posted sideways so I turned it right side up for you. I also took your personal name out of the question itself.  Having it as your profile name is plenty, and there's no need to thanks us, that's what we're here for! We look forward to getting you some help with your plant.

Comment: Thank you so much ... Is my personal information included in my 2nd post?  If so, how do I fix it so you guys don’t have to?  Thanks Robin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too much water or too much fertilizer.  Unless you've over watered?  Same symptoms.  Please tell us more detail about what you've done what you have added. This plant was doing fantastically and then something recently changed.

You have to tell us every detail you are able to think of!  No matter how small.  did you take it out of doors in the sun?  Did you use boiling water?  ha ha. Did you fertilize with something recently?  Does this pot have a drainage hole?  What kind of soil is in this pot?

Something changed just recently.

UPDATE:

Well I wasn't expecting the drive in HOT weather from Tucson all the way to the beach and back?...did she make sure this plant was never in the sun out of doors?  Did she keep the air conditioner on when she wasn't in the car? Just taking the plant from its normal environment was stressful.

When I ordered plants from the nursery, they would arrive in a refrigerated, air conditioned truck.  Only minutes from the nursery.  What did this plant look like after it arrived at your home after mom's vacation?  This was a monumental stressful vacation for your mom's plant.  Kind of a cute idea but plants aren't meant to travel around at all.

If she left them in a too hot car (over 85 degrees F) or allowed this plant to sit in a too hot car without enough water, that would cause this majorly unhappy plant.  Ask her if the plant ever found itself in direct sun...for 15 minutes? Plants are unable to move to get out of the sun or heat or water to survive.

*Please send another picture so we can see how this plant is recuperating?* This does not look good, not one bit.  Bummer. But plants can surprise us humans! Hope it enjoyed the vacation!  Sweet but deadly.

A picture now would tell us if it might make it.  *Please pop the entire root ball out of the pot and take a peek at those roots, take a picture.*  Plants in pots have the most fragile part of their anatomy exposed to temperatures; hot and cold. The roots. The roots might have been cooked.  Or rotted from too much water because the plant shut down.  Stopped the photosynthesizing and uptake of water.

Update two:

Those roots and the seed look healthy!  Ugh, put it back into fresh potting soil! Moisten the roots and cover with newspaper while you prepare the pot and soil.  Or is this last picture this plant replanted in the original pot?  Good!.

You really dived into this problem!  I am impressed, probably not a great thing for the plant but you are getting to know this plant intimately!  Very good.  I think that this guy needs a larger pot by 2" wider in diameter, perhaps even 3 or 4 inches.  Clay.

Then some pruning is in order to reduce the plant's top growth a bit.  The roots look just fine.  It might have been a response to all the stress it has been through.  I'd like to see a fresh picture of the leaves at this point.  I also think this should be in YOUR family of plants! Grins!

Comment: This is actually my Mother’s plant.  It was doing fantastic until about a month ago when she took it on a 2 week vacation to Huntington Beach California.  The plant loved the ocean air in a shaded area in the backyard.  The drive was 2 days each way in the car.  Then back to Tucson AZ in a south facing window with little direct sun light.  It is probably over watered a bit too.  My Mother is out of state again and I am watching it.  She returns next week and wants to re-plant it into a larger pot.  I have no idea what soil she has it in now.  Any suggestions on soil in the new pot?

Comment: I have not watered it in 4 days, thinking it was over watered.  There is a hole on the bottom of this pot.  That’s all I can think of.  Will it live?

Comment: New pictures at the top of the page.  It seems like it’s taking a long time to die.

Comment: Updated 9/13 ...  Mom is home now and we are going to plant it a bigger pot tomorrow.  I’ll send a closeup picture of the leaves and new pot.  The window that the plant sits at does have direct sunlight for a few hour a day.  The window has a special screen on it so the direct sunlight isn’t too bad.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would ease it into the direct sunlight even at this stage.  It's epidermis is probably thinned because of the intensity of the light it experienced on its vacation.  Sorry, I just think it is just too cute of your mom to take this guy on her vacation, probably 'cause you were busy?  No matter, there is vitality in those roots.  I can help look at how to cut off some of the material to make life easier for this plant, or see whether it is better to leave as is.

Comment: I’ve handed the plant over to Mom and told her if she needs great advise get it here!  Thanks for all your help!